# Create beta subdomain to my main site with these parameters below

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, dns, subdomain

I want to redirect (beta.mysite.com) subdomain, which is on another server (I only changed the DNS A record) to my main domain site, but would like to send with parameters like mysite.com?beta=1, and keep the subdomain url like beta.mysite.com.

On the main site I'd like to check the url (with get method) and if it's equal with my conditions I'd change the content with PHP.

Is this possible to do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not possible the way you describe it, you cannot somehow trick a client to send requests to another server than what he actually shows in the URL. What you _can_ do: you can "mask" the actual server behind what you call the "beta subdomain", so behind another host which acts as a transparent proxy. So all requests are sent to `beta` which _internally_ forwards requests and responses, so that the client does not know about the actual serving host. The apache http server comes with a proxy module. Consult the excellent documentation on how to use it.

Comment: I see! Thanks for the explanation. I feel I've more to learn about how the web actually works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will require a reverse proxy server to do that. Which you can setup on `beta.mysite.com` and perform the proxy request with additional params.

You can use any of the reverse proxy servers . eg. HAPROXY, nginx etc.